# Three.js WebGL renderer not updating Color property on faces

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I have a simple plane mesh where i want to change the color of a face at run-time (actually when a character walks over the "floor tile").

I try the following:

```
face.color.setRGB(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random());
```

This works fine with `CanvasRenderer`, but when i switch to `WebGLRenderer`, it stops working.

I have tried setting the `geometry.colorsNeedUpdate` flag, with no success, the mesh and the geometry are set as `dynamic`, is there something else i am missing?

(Using Three.js r59)

Thanks,

Phil.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For `WebGLRenderer`, here is the pattern you need to follow for `THREE.Geometry`.

Assign a color to each face.

```
for ( var i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length; i ++ ) {
    geometry.faces[ i ].color.setHex( Math.random() * 0xffffff );
}
```

Set `vertexColors = THREE.FaceColors` in the material.

```
material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors } );
```

Set `colorsNeedsUpdate` after a color change.

```
mesh.geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;
```

three.js.r.76

Comment: For anyone with a similar problem, it seems to work when i set the flag through the mesh (mesh.geometry.colorsNeedUpdate), but NOT when i refer to geometry directly (geometry.colorsNeedUpdate) - I guess that the geometry variable is copied (rather than referenced)  when its fed into the mesh, which makes sense if there are multiple meshes based on one geometry.

Comment: i tried your comment but didn't help, but what helped for me for some reason is adding geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true; in my render loop

Comment: Don't forget to have - vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors in your material

Answer (score 1):

As per [Geometry](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/core/Geometry) Document, To signal an update in this faces, `Geometry.elementsNeedUpdate` needs to be set to true.

The following snippet changes the colors of all faces.

```
var faces = mesh.geometry.faces;

for(var i = 0 ; i < faces.length; i++){
  var face = faces[i];
  var color = new THREE.Color("rgb(255, 0, 0)");
  face.color = color;
}

mesh.geometry.elementsNeedUpdate = true;

render();
```

Comment: Do NOT instantiate a new `THREE.Color` if face colors already exist. Instead do `faces[ i ].color.setRGB( 1, 0, 0 );` and then `mesh.geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;`. Re-read the referenced doc.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;` instead of `needsColorUpdate`?